# rename multiple files using substring of the filename

Tags: powershell

I have 100's of file in windows with names like

```
W-cat_T_1001_s.jpg
W-dog_T_12112_o.jpg
W-rabbit_T_121_w.jpg
```

i want to rename all the files to its substring for example

```
cat.jpg
dog.jpg 
rabbit.jpg
```

My approach was to first replace `"_T_*"` with "" in powerShell something like

```
DIR| Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "_T_*", ""}
```

this gives error

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'z' does not exist
```

i don't know whether it was a right approach and whether it is good to use PowerShell, batch file, java or simple "rename" command will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir |  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'W-(.*)_T_.*','$1.jpg'}
```